# I can't enqueue Suggest.js in frontend - not added

Tags: jquery, actions, wp-enqueue-script, front-end, frontpage

my suggest.js is not being added in front-end. All scripts are correctly loaded but this one. I want to load it only on frontpage so:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'homescripts');
function homescripts()  
{ 
   if (is_front_page()):
   wp_enqueue_script('suggest');
   endif;
}
```

and in my home's html

```
<script>
jQuery("#my_input").suggest("<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ajax-tag-search&tax=my_taxonomy", {multiple:true, multipleSep: ","});
</script>
```

where `#my_input` is my input field I want with suggestions and `tax=my_taxonomy` is the source taxonomy.

Is there something worng I'm doing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you registered the script (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) before enqueuing it?

Comment: I'm trying to use the internal wordpress script "suggest.js". Should I register even it? @Caspar

Comment: In that case, no, you shouldn't need to register it. Next place I'd look is whether I've got the right template... check difference/usage between home.php and front-page.php. Is the suggest script present on the output page? If so, the problem is with home html script.

Comment: Ok but that is working fine. I've just checked. Now I see the sugges.min.js loaded but I get this error "TypeError: jQuery(...).suggest is not a function"... JQuery and Suggest.min.js are loaded in the correct order. Any suggestion? @Caspar

Comment: With the disclaimer that I'm not really a jQuery expert, see the answer below. Probably the best I've got at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you've confirmed that WP's native 'suggest' script is actually being rendered on the page properly (ie. you're using the correct template for home vs front-page), sometimes to avoid script conflicts on the page, you need to wrap your script in an anonymous function. So something like:

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $("#my_input").suggest("<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ajax-tag-search&tax=my_taxonomy", {
        multiple: true,
        multipleSep: ","
    });
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

Ideally, this should also be separated off into its own .js file and registered/enqueued properly on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook with 'suggest' declared as a dependency:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-suggest', 'path/to/my-suggest.js', array( 'suggest' ), false, true );
```